# LUKS passphase promt blackscreen on Arch with nvidia

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, luks

i am new to Arch (coming from Debian) and apart from the following it's working pretty good.

So i installed Arch according to the guide on the wiki and also set up my encrypted /home partition (Note: Only /home is encrypted, the root filesystem on my ssd is not).

So upon first boot i can see all the services starting up, and at some point it's asking me for my passphrase for /home. That's how it's supposed to be.

Since this is my Desktop computer i then installed the nvidia drivers and x.org

```
  pacman -S xorg-server xorg-server-utils
  pacman -S nvidia nvidia-libgl nvidia-settings
```

Then i installed my DE

```
pacman -S mate mate-extra
```

And also lightdm

```
pacman -S lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

So far so good.
The problem is, that if i reboot, at the point where i am supposed to enter my passphrase the screen turns black. If i blindly enter my passphrase the boot continues as usual and the lightdm greeter comes up.
So i guess it works, but i would rather like to see the terminal and possible error messages in case i mistyped it.

I recorded the boot process and looked at it frame-by-frame and saw that the services are booting up as usual, then it asks for a passphrase and THEN immediately after the screen turns black.

So what can i do to prevent that? I didn't find anything useful on the internet. The only stuff i found was about changing something in the boot config for when you also have the root partition encrypted or changing something in the config of plymouth, but i don't use plymouth.

Comment: Do you have a [/etc/crypttab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#crypttab)?

Comment: Try adding "nosplash" (and/or remove "splash") and "nomodeset" to the kernel command line.  Also try removing "quiet".  This can usually be done temporarily at the boot prompt, or by editing `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` if you use `grub` for booting.  (This is not permanent, as the file is generated, but you can change the defaults after testing this.)

Comment: Adding nosplash and nomodeset did the trick. Thank you